# Как лучше организовать поиск и вывод большого количества данных?

Tags: c++, qt

Я разрабатываю редактор кода для html, css, php, js в Qt. Мне нужно, чтобы после каждого изменения пользователем кода в текстовом поле программа пробегала по данным и выводила начинающиеся с того, что ввел пользователь ключевые слова/функции. Список прототипов функций для php у меня [есть](https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше организовать поиск нужных слов в этом огромном количестве информации? Ведь нужно, чтобы все это работало очень быстро. Смотрю в сторону баз данных. Тогда мне нужно будет спарсить все stub'ы с github'a(ссылка выше) и записать их в базу данных.
Или есть путь получше? Как вообще поступают умные люди в таких случаях?

Прикрепленное изображение - то, что я хочу получить в итоге.

[image: vs - screenshot]

Comment: умные люди делают дерево, по буквам. или держут список отсортированным и используют бинарный поиск.

Comment: бинарный поиск долговато. Я бы посоветовал бор или алгоритм Ахо-Корасик.

Comment: бинарный поиск медленный? а бор - это сокращение от "перебор"?

Но если уже решили предложить Ахо-Корасик, то как именно? все имена функций собрать в одну строку и по ней искать? это будет точно медленее, чем даже прямой перебор.

Comment: @KoVadim бор это от слова словарное дерево) А по поводу Ахо-Корасика там хитрее. Оно позволяет построить конечный автомат для поиска вхождений _всех_ подстрок. Вроде бы именно это и надо. Ахо-Корасик это модернизированный бор можно считать.

Comment: @pavel то есть лучше загрузить все функции и ключевые слова в какой нибудь Qset/Qmap и потом по ним искать? Не накладно будет заносить такой объем в оперативную память?

Comment: давайте упростим задачу. Вам нужно сделать следующее - есть список функций, и нужно по префиксу (первым символам слова) находить подходящие имена? 
Не будет ли это "много в памяти"? нет, не будет. Там всего то 3470 функций.

Comment: @KoVadim разве 3470? Кажется, что их намного больше. Да и 
представлены они в том репозитории весьма странно. Вы случайно не знаете, где можно найти список этих функций в более нормальном виде?

Comment: Я просто прогрепал по файлам с репозитория. Теоретически мог немного ошибиться в количестве, но не на порядок. А весь список - это вряд ли. Библиотек и фреймворков вагон и тележка.

Comment: @KoVadim не подскажете, что это за форма записи функций в репозитории? А откуда вообще берут все эти функции для подсказок при вводе разработчики редакторов кода? Мне хотя бы просто чтобы стандартные подсказывать, без фреймворков.

Comment: в данном репозитории лежат файлы, с функций которых поудаляли "тело" - что бы они были меньше и легче парсились.

Где берут разработчики редакторов кода все это? два варианта - либо хардкодят (то есть генерируют список ручками), либо пишут полноценный парсер, который все сам и делает.

Comment: @KoVadim Хардкодят - т.е. просто пишут вручную список, верно? А парсер что парсить должен? php.net?

Comment: хардкод - да, вручную. А парсер парсит исходники. И если они изменяются, то и список изменяется.

Comment: @KoVadim Так так, это становится очень интересным. А где в таком случае взять исходники php и javascript, чтобы их пропарсить и сгенерировать список функций?

Comment: Давайте поделим сорцы на две части - те, которые явно можно взять (собственно библиотеки, Ваш код) и код php/javascript.
С первым проблем нет - оно лежит рядышком. А вот с вторым немножко накладнее. И тут либо нужно парсить документацию,  либо сделать как разработчики выше - нагенерировать код-заглушку. И тогда один и тот же парсер кода все сам парсит.

Comment: @KoVadim ну так неужели разработчики сидели и писали вручную все эти километры кода stub'ов? Они же тоже откуда - то брали эти функции, как можно на генерировать этот код заглушку?

Comment: нет конечно, никто вручную не делал. Спарсили php.net и нагенерировали. Если присмотреться, то это видно невооруженным глазом. Например, для curl. Там даже урлы остались

Comment: @KoVadim ну вот, с PHP все более менее понятно - есть php.net, который можно спарсить. С html/css тоже более менее все ясно - можно с notepad'a стянуть, либо спарсить htmlbook. А вот как быть с javascriptoм? У него нет нормального, централизованного справочника, на JavaScript.ru по-моему есть не все функции, а те что есть, оформлены не очень - math.abs(x), а не math.abs(Number x).

Comment: @KoVadim последнее, что хочу спросить, вы сказали, что лучше загрузить этот список функций в оперативную память при запуске программы т. е. в контейнер qset/qmap. Но при таком подходе, если я захочу добавить еще языков программирования, программа будет сжирать все больше оперативной памяти. Как тогда быть?

Comment: А зачем все держать в одном списке. Если html и PHP может смешиваться в одном файле, то с(+ и Erlang - вряд ли.  И подгружать такие списки можно по надобности.э, а не все сразу.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо за ответ! а если пользователь откроет несколько вкладок - в одной PHP, в другой c++, в третей erlang

Comment: Загрузите три списка. Закроет вкладку - выгрузите.

Comment: @KoVadim а скорость баз данных ниже, чем контейнеры? (может просто все в базе хранить)

Comment: Если максимально идеально написать, то скорости думаю будут равны. Но в Вашем случае контейнер будет быстрее и практичнее.